# Where are rvalues stored in C++?

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference

I'm learning new C++ 11 features recently. However, I don't fully understand one thing about rvalues.

Consider following code:

```
string getText ()
{
    return "Fabricati diem";
}

string newText = getText();
```

Call to `getText()` creates an r-value which is copied to `newText` variable. But where exactly is this rvalue stored? And what happens to it after copying?

Comment: Actually it is not copied due to [return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization)

Comment: @Cyber It can't be moved *and* RVO'd. It is one or the other, most likely the latter.

Comment: isn't stack the answer?

Comment: Expressions can be (have to be either) rvalue or lvalue expressions. Values themselves are not rvalue or lvalue. Yes, it's a bit misleading terminology.

Comment: The answer depends on the compilation target. The standard doesn't specify that. If that function wasn't RVO-able, the string would probably be stored somewhere in .rdata/.rodata (so, technically on the heap).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Call to getText() creates an r-value which is copied to newText variable.

It might create a temporary; but this is one situation in which [*copy elision*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127) is allowed, so it's more likely that `newText` is initialised directly by the function return, with no temporary.

> But where exactly is this rvalue stored?

It's up to the compiler where to store a temporary; the standard only specifies its lifetime. Typically, it will be treated like an automatic variable, stored in registers or in the function's stack frame.

> And what happens to it after copying?

The lifetime of a temporary extends to the end of the full-expression which created it (unless it's used to initialise a referenece, in which case it lasts as long as that reference). So here, it's destroyed immediately after using it to initialise `newText`.